# How to create a Drupal 8 distribution

Tags: users, distributions, installation-profiles, 8

So I have this Drupal 8 site with its custom theme, some blocks, menus, content types, views and other more stuff. What I am required to do is create a site distribution of this site for drupal.org, but I have absolutely no idea of how to do it.

I created the profile folder in **doctoot/profiles** and created the info.yml with the profile basic information. I also have the **.install** and **.profile** files but they are empty. These files were created using `drupal generate:profile`

After that I exported the config YAML files using `drush config:export`, but they were created in **config\sync** in the profile folder, but I saw in another distributions that these files are located in **config\install** rather than **sync**,and I don't know if that makes a difference.

I don't have anything besides that and I don't know what to do after that to configure things in the distribution in terms of theme and configuration. I have the project page in drupal.org already with the git configuration. Hope you can help me with this issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to create an installation profile.

Follow the instructions on drupal.

[How to write a D8 profile](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-distributions/how-to-write-a-drupal-8-installation-profile)

Move the files from the config/sync folder to config/install folder. Be sure to delete core.extension.yml and remove all UUIDs.

Optionally, you can try this project:[project config_installer](https://www.drupal.org/project/config_installer)

Comment: I have done that, deleted the core.extensions.yml and put the dependencies in the info.yml, and after that? I'm lost, because most decumentation is for Drupal 7, Thanks in advance for the answer.

Comment: 1. Pick up a machine name with underscores only 2. create profilename.info.yml with all dependencies an language 3. create .install file 4.  Copy all the files from /config folder into config/install without UUIDs 5. delete core.extension.yml and be sure all modules an themes were listed in .info.yml file